# How to handle alpha layer of images in css?

Tags: html, css, image, button, alpha

I was trying to make a image button.The images have alpha layer in them. The alpha layer is not blending properly and instead of transparency, I am getting a white background.

I don't know how to fix this. Please help. I want the image buttons to show the color of layer benath them rather than the white.

```css
.footer-icon-list {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #0f1720;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;

}

.Facebook-buttom{
    margin: auto;
    border: none;
    background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AayushPokharel/ContentDeliveryRepo/master/facebook.png");
    background-size: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.Instagram-buttom{
    margin: auto;
    border: none;
    background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AayushPokharel/ContentDeliveryRepo/master/instagram.png");
    background-size: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.Twitter-buttom{
    margin: auto;
    border: none;
    background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AayushPokharel/ContentDeliveryRepo/master/twitter.png");
    background-size: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.Github-buttom{
    margin: auto;
    border: none;
    background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AayushPokharel/ContentDeliveryRepo/master/github.png");
    background-size: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div className="footer-icon-list">
  <span><button className="Facebook-buttom"></button></span>
  <span><button className="Instagram-buttom"></button></span>
  <span><button className="Twitter-buttom"></button></span>
  <span><button className="Github-buttom"></button></span>
</div>
```

This is how it looks. I want the white border to be transparent and show the underlaying background color.

[image: How my result looks.]

Comment: can you please merge your code to a [repro] (stacksnippet, `Ctrl+m` or `<>`-button) and add the pictures directly as an `absolute url`

Comment: Have you cleared the cache in the browser? Never develop while having cache activated.

Comment: @RickardElimää I found the problem, he wants to put an image inside a button. a button is always grey by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you put the image inside a `<button>`! *<<this is the problem*

the default behavior of a `<button>` is to be grey.

just add a `inherit` value to `background-color` css property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit

```css
background-color: inherit;
```

> I also refactored your code, because it has a lot of repetitive code, 
> the images are fine! they are `.png` so they are fine

[image]

```css
.footer-icon-list {
    /* this is your background of the parent
    I suggest you to change it (grey on black don't have a good contrast) */
    background-color: #0f1720;
    /* this shortcut set the bottom and top with the 10px */
    padding: 10px 0;
    /* centering */
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.footer-icon-list span button {
    margin: auto;
    border: none;
    background-size: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    /* the solution */
    background-color: inherit;
}


/* images */

.Facebook-buttom {
    background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AayushPokharel/ContentDeliveryRepo/master/facebook.png");
}

.Instagram-buttom {
    background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AayushPokharel/ContentDeliveryRepo/master/instagram.png");
}

.Twitter-buttom {
    background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AayushPokharel/ContentDeliveryRepo/master/twitter.png");
}

.Github-buttom {
    background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AayushPokharel/ContentDeliveryRepo/master/github.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-icon-list">
  <!-- 1 -->
  <span><button class="Facebook-buttom"></button></span>
  <!-- 2 -->
  <span><button class="Instagram-buttom"></button></span>
  <!-- 3 -->
  <span><button class="Twitter-buttom"></button></span>
  <!-- 4 -->
  <span><button class="Github-buttom"></button></span>
</div>
```